# How to authenticate with another auth provider using Supabase?

Tags: node.js, jwt, sveltekit, supabase, supabase-database

I'm making a website that can basically read and write data to a Supabase database. It's using [FluffyScratch](https://github.com/hamptonmoore/FluffyScratch) auth. FluffyScratch isn't supported by Supabase so I need to implement an authentication solution. I did a search and I found out that Supabase has support of other authentication methods and that I need to use JWTs. I've already got some code that signs the JWT.

It uses the FluffyScratch authentication method. First I send the user to the FluffyScratch page, then the user get redirected back to my website with a private code as a query parameter, then fetch the FluffyScratch verification API on a SvelteKit endpoint to see if their private code is actually valid and that the user owns the Scratch account they say they do.

So I think that the next part of making this work is going to be getting the JWT to authenticate with Supabase. I've been looking around but I'm a bit confused on how to make Supabase accept this token. The signUp function in GoTrue only accepts email, password or a phone number so I don't think that I would have much success with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I'm doing in my case may work for you if you happen to come across this question.

I'm signing my own JWTs with the `jsonwebtoken` NPM package. I'm using `dotenv` to get my JWT signing key (also my supabase url, and key) since `VITE_` prefixed environment variables are exposed on the client. Then I can use the same `jsonwebtoken` NPM package to verify the signature and then my users can use FluffyScratch and I can use Supabase.